# Using custom Appsync queries with the Amplify-Android sdk

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-sdk-android

I have a custom query in my schema with its own pipeline resolver set up:

```
type Query {
    getMomentAppendView(mid: ID!): Moment
}
```

I am unsure what codegen labels it as in the Amplify framework.  In the tutorials I only see how to get the pre-made queries for models.  For example, on a simple `@model` (like `Moment`, above.)

```kotlin
Amplify.API.query(
    // Return a single item
    ModelQuery.get(Moment::class.java, mid),
    { resp ->
        val response = Response<Moment>()
        response.data = resp.data as Moment
        response.isSuccessful = true
        cont.resume(response)
    },
    { error ->
        val response = Response<Moment>()
        response.throwable = error
        response.isSuccessful = false
        cont.resume(response)
    }
)
```

How do I execute my custom GraphQL query?

Comment: The Amplify team is currently working on documentation for this use case. You can see some in-progress documentation here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/docs/pull/2141 In short, you can create your own `GraphQLRequest`, and pass that to `Amplfy.API.query(...)`, instead of using the `ModelQuery` utility. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/blob/main/aws-api-appsync/src/main/java/com/amplifyframework/api/aws/AppSyncGraphQLRequest.java#L206